# Removing signature image from PDF

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, image-processing

I have signed a PDF to send it online (I did with `xournal` I think). They wanted it per post. I printed it and sent it, they wanted the signature handwritten. I need to remove the signature from the PDF and print it. I do not want to fill the original again. I have tried several things:

- `xournal`: not possible to select the signature image from the PDF
- `LibreOffice`: works fine (I can remove the images), but messes up formatting when opening the PDF (I think it is lacking fonts)
- `Gimp`: converting the PDF to an image allows me to edit the image, but removing the signatures (there are a lot of them) is difficult (I would need to make sure that I replace the signature with the background, which is not always a simple plain color)

So, what I need is to do the following:

```
pdf-processor list-image-objects myfile.pdf

object1
object2
object3
```

Now, assuming that object1 and object3 are the signatures that I want to remove, I would do:

```
pdf-processor remove-image-objects object1 object3 myfile.pdf -o output.pdf
```

Is there such a command line program `pdf-processor`?